# NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass): at /oauth/authorize with doorkeeper

Tags: rails-api, doorkeeper

I am working on making my API an Oauth provider using Doorkeeper, when I make a request to `/oauth/authorize`, I get the error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
```

After digging into the gem, I discovered that the error comes from this place in the gem https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/326a75a0633fdfd92c3259607636349173bb5fbb/app/controllers/doorkeeper/authorizations_controller.rb#L47

So, I added this to my application_controller

```rb
def current_resource_owner
    User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id) if doorkeeper_token
 end
```

I have the configuration for doorkeeper here - https://gist.github.com/kinsomicrote/7ddd438e7cc542d173551a1d0ff4e948

I expect to get back an authorization code. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you got solution ? I also have same issue

Answer (score 0):

You request to `/oauth/authorize` so you are using authorization_code flow, or implicit flow of Oauth2 (please also check it out to get some info about those authorization flow of Oauth2)
the `current_resource_owner` method is defined [here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/4dd7c514e40eb8aea196f1bcf219ab234fc2e89e/lib/doorkeeper/helpers/controller.rb#L18), then the `authenticate_resource_owner` configuration is [called here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/4dd7c514e40eb8aea196f1bcf219ab234fc2e89e/lib/doorkeeper/helpers/controller.rb#L22).
That configuration is defined as `resource_owner_authenticator` at [here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/a94b280c145f3c6cacccb064f3945bd868019306/lib/doorkeeper/config.rb#L225-L226).

So you need to config [your resource_owner_authenticator](https://gist.github.com/kinsomicrote/7ddd438e7cc542d173551a1d0ff4e948#file-doorkeeper-rb-L9)! There is example [here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/0ed35c7ba873fecb4eb9c1159862fb2262da4c84/spec/dummy/config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb#L8-L11).

But currently you are configuring [resource_owner_from_credentials](https://gist.github.com/kinsomicrote/7ddd438e7cc542d173551a1d0ff4e948#file-doorkeeper-rb-L16), which indeed is for `Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant` of Oauth2, which is used as [here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/2e6d53f28a6cd356bc500c05d0f653ebe40255c8/spec/requests/flows/password_spec.rb#L25-L26)